# Shall a web service accept local dateTime values?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am writing code that is required to interact with a certain third-party *SOAP* web-service via the *SOAP*-client mechanism built into the system in which I work. Among other data, the web-service accepts several `dateTime` fields in incoming parameters to its web-methods, and I am stuck with passing those fields in a sort of a dead-end. The web-service requires that the `dateTime` fields contain an explicit timezone, whereas the *SOAP* wrapper I must use supports only so-called *untimezoned* `dateTime` values, that is ones without a specified timezone.

So we have a server and a client claiming to support a certain protocol yet unable to interact over it, which means that at least one of them is broken (or both, for that matter), and I need your help in identifying the culprit(s).

Accroding to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime), a timezone specifier is optional in `dateTime`, and software seems to be required to interpret *untimezoned* values as having some default timezone:

> "Local" or untimezoned times are presumed to be the time in the timezone of some unspecified locality as prescribed by the appropriate legal authority;

which seems to imply that the web-service is wrong in complaining about the `dateTime` format without a timezone, and that it must accept *untimezoned* values as well, interpreting in terms of some openly documented default timezone. Is my interpretation correct? If it is, the SOAP client is not to blame, because it can always convert its times into the default timezone before submission...

Am I also right that the *SOAP* client-wrapper is also deficient, in that it does not fully support the `dateTime` type of *XML Schema*?